# How am I supposed to create an HTML table in PHP file?

Tags: php

I am trying to create an HTML table dynamically. Apparently, I am doing something wrong but what? Please help!

```
$foo_connection = db_connect($host, $user_name, $user_password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT id, heading FROM articles"; 

$result = mysqli_query($foo_connection, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    print "<table>";

    foreach($result as $key => $cols) {

         print "<tr><td>".$cols['id']."</td>"."<td>".$cols['heading']."</td></tr>";

    }

    print "</table>";

}

else {
    print "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($foo_connection);
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova print $cols['id']." ".$cols['heading'];

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa4b76591a84ef80905115399fbf47a575311c5a  Are you sure that you're actually running this as PHP?

Comment: Check if your `$result` variable is not empty.

Comment: I uploaded the whole php code

Answer (score 3):

instead of it do this.

```
<?php
   //your code
   ?>

<table>
<?php
   foreach ($result as $key => $cols) {
   ?>
<tr>
   <td> <?php echo $cols['id']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $cols['heading']; ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php
   }
   ?>
```

here you can easily find what is the problem then echoing all HTML fields. this is my suggestion.